# JMeter fails on beanshell imports

Tags: cookies, import, jmeter, invoke, beanshell

I had been using Beanshell pre-processor to add custom cookies created through javascript. While it used to work perfectly earlier, with the same line of codes I started to recieve errors in my pre-processor.

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager; import org.apache. . . . '' : TargetError 


WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager; import org.apache. . . . '' : TargetError
```

The lines of code is as per suggestion provided in https://javaworks.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/setting-cookie-in-jmeter/

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

try{
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("cookie1","value","localhost","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie1);

}catch (Throwable ex) {
log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
throw ex;
}
```

I came across several post in stackoverflow related to beanshell. However, none answers why imports in beanshell are failing. The error log:

```
018/07/02 16:24:47 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Error in Beanshell java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.match(CookieManager.java:386)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.removeMatchingCookies(CookieManager.java:402)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.add(CookieManager.java:307)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80)
at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858)
at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:46)
at bsh.BSHTryStatement.eval(BSHTryStatement.java:86)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:163)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.eval(BeanShellInterpreter.java:186)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement.processFileOrScript(BeanShellTestElement.java:151)
at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor.process(BeanShellPreProcessor.java:59)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:786)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:445)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, there is no need in scripting, you can add custom cookies using [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) GUI

   [image: JMeter add cookie via GUI]
2. If you still want to code try upgrading to the [latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
3. Try playing with different "Policy" values in the HTTP Cookie Manager, i.e. try using `standard` or `netscape`
4. Try adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
5. In general [it is recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language since JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy).

Comment: Dmitri, the values of the cookies in my application needs to be updated frequently within a single loop whenever user navigates to new page, so I need to use preprocessor. however, even with JSR223 I get java null point error. Do I need any extra jar when I import CookieManager/Cookie in my preprocessor?

Comment: The point it to **have** the HTTP Cookie Manager **added** to your test plan and it has to be in the Sampler's [Scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules). You should not need any extra jars as Cookie Manager is a part of JMeter HTTP protocol module and it should be already in your classpath. See [Modifying Cookies in JMeter with Groovy
](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy) guide for more details on cookies manipulation from scripts if needed